# Cassandra single node installation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I just try to install `cassandra` on my `ubuntu:12.04`. Steps i have followed

```
  Installed java version 1.7.XX and verified with java -version
  apt-get install libjna-java  //Installs jna
  python 2.7 is installed already

  Extracted to /usr/local/installables/
  Successfully extracted.

  Then I set cassandra home

  export CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/local/installables/dse-2.2.2/resources/cassandra
  export PATH=$PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
```

pscenter.tar.gz dse.tar.gz

```
  I created /var/cassandra/saved_caches, /var/cassandra/data, /var/cassandra/commitlog

  I updated cassandra-env.sh -Xss 280 from 180

  I left listen_address as empty, rpc_address as 0.0.0.0 and seed ip as 127.0.0.1 

  I left jmx port as 7199. I left all the default config in cassandra.yaml
```

Now i tried to run cassandra

```
  /usr/local/installbles/dse/cassandra/bin/cassandra
```

It says

```
  xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/local/installables/dse-2.2.2/resources/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1954M -Xmx1954M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss280k
 Error: Could not find or load main class com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon
```

So I can understand i missed some installation config steps of dse. Please let me know whats the error and any links to set up single node cassandra setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong command to start it. If you have dse installed then the command would be:

```
<path to dse bin>/dse cassandra
```

This will start dse running in the background. If you want to run it in the foreground then:

```
<path to dse bin>/dse cassandra -f
```

Comment: It says "Connection refused at port 9160". I checked nothing is listening at port 9160. But i get into cassandra commandline with this exception

Comment: I started using /dse/bin/cassandra-cli . If i use your command, it says cassandra no command found.

Comment: The above command is starting a cassandra server so shouldn't say connection refused. Does the server start up correctly with the above command?

Comment: Output of that command is same as in [this qs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629833/cant-able-to-start-cassandra-services?noredirect=1#comment45561277_28629833)

Comment: In this question and the other question it is obvious that your server isn't started so if you could post the output from the above command we will be able to help you.

Comment: `'Starting up server gossip
 INFO 16:57:28,129 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-LocationInfo@1681585027(126/157 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
 INFO 16:57:28,130 Writing Memtable-LocationInfo@1681585027(126/157 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
 INFO 16:57:28,208 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo/system-LocationInfo-hf-1-Data.db (234 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1424451447940, position=605)
 INFO 16:57:28,232 Starting Messaging Service on port 7000
 INFO 16:57:28,239 JOINING: waiting for ring information` This is the current output. Is it correct?

Comment: Nodetool status will tell you when your up