# Can't able to start Cassandra Services

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I just downloaded tar ball and extracted it. Steps i have done is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626365/cassandra-single-node-installation)

```
path/dse/bin/cassandra-cli
```

It says Connection refused at port 9160

```
netstat -plten
```

returns no process on 9160. So cassandra service is not started. How to start it? DO i need to set any env variables or config changes? I am setting up just single node setup.

```
 org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.ja                                                                     va:81)

.........................

Exception connecting to 127.0.0.1/9160. Reason: Connection refused.
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.1.9-dse-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Any help?

Comment: Your server isn't started. Look at the output from `cassandra -f` and share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run `/<dse directory>/bin/dse cassandra` on a [tarball install](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installTARdse.html) or `service dse start` on a package install to start DSE. Only when the DSE service is running can you connect to it. Check if it's running with `ps -ef|grep dse`

By the way, note that cassandra-cli is deprecated. Use [cqlsh](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html) instead!

Comment: Good call mentioning cqlsh vs. cassandra-cli.  I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Search with -s analytics with -k

Comment: Thanks Man. I 'll try or if i face problem, i 'll post another question